# Changing simultaneously text and image on slider

Tags: javascript, slider

I made a slider with a series of images. I created two buttons (prev and next) that allow browsing the images.

I created also two divs where I put the slide's number and title.
**My goal is to change the image, number, and title of the slide simultaneously each time a click event on prev or next buttons occurs.**

I have started programming some months ago and I am having difficulties associating images with corresponding titles and numbers.

Could someone help me complete my code?
Actually, the following code works for me to show the image on click but is not complete.
I would like to change all the elements (image, title and number) at the same time after click.

More details on the picture:[Screen of the homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAynI.jpg)

```js
// Carousel
let sliderImage = document.querySelector(".sliderImage");
let images = [
  "carousel1.jpg",
  "carousel2.jpg",
  "carousel3.jpg",
  "carousel4.jpg",
  "carousel5.jpg",
  "carousel6.jpg",
  "carousel7.jpg",
];

let i = 0; // Current image index

// I have already created in html file 2 btns with "onclick" event
// that trigger the following functions:

function prev() {
  if (i <= 0) i = images.length;
  i--;
  return getSlideImg();
}

function next() {
  if (i >= images.length - 1) i = -1;
  i++;
  return getSlideImg();
}

function getSlideImg() {
  return sliderImage.setAttribute("src", "img/" + images[i]);
}
```

```html
<!-- Carousel -->
      <div class="carousel-container">
        <div class="carousel-slide">

          <img src="./img/carousel1.jpg" alt="" class="sliderImage"/>

          <!-- Carousel card -->
          <div class="carousel__card-container">
            <div class="carousel__card-title">Soggiorno</div>
            <div class="carousel__slide-data">
              <div class="slide__number">01</div>
              <div class="slide__loader">
                <div class="loader__line-grey">
                  <div class="loader__line-white"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Carousel buttons -->
          <div class="carousel-btn">
            <a href="#" class="button left-arrow bottone" id="prevBtn" onclick="prev()">
              <i class="ri-arrow-left-s-line btn-icon-small"></i>
            </a>

            <a href="#" class="button right-arrow bottone" id="nextBtn" onclick="next()">
              <i class="ri-arrow-right-s-line btn-icon-small"></i>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

set all values inside `getSlideImg` function so everything will update with corresponding image

```js
// Carousel
let sliderImage = document.querySelector(".sliderImage"),
    container = document.querySelector(".carousel-container")
let images = [
  "carousel1.jpg",
  "carousel2.jpg",
  "carousel3.jpg",
  "carousel4.jpg",
  "carousel5.jpg",
  "carousel6.jpg",
  "carousel7.jpg",
];

let i = 0; // Current image index

// I have already created in html file 2 btns with "onclick" event
// that trigger the following functions:

function prev() {
  if (i <= 0) i = images.length;
  i--;
  return getSlideImg();
}

function next() {
  if (i >= images.length - 1) i = -1;
  i++;
  return getSlideImg();
}

function getSlideImg() {
  container.querySelector(".slide__number").innerText = i + 1
  container.querySelector(".carousel__card-title").innerText = images[i]
  return sliderImage.setAttribute("src", "img/" + images[i]);
}

// for onload
getSlideImg()
```

```html
<!-- Carousel -->
      <div class="carousel-container">
        <div class="carousel-slide">

          <img src="./img/carousel1.jpg" alt="" class="sliderImage"/>

          <!-- Carousel card -->
          <div class="carousel__card-container">
            <div class="carousel__card-title">Soggiorno</div>
            <div class="carousel__slide-data">
              <div class="slide__number">01</div>
              <div class="slide__loader">
                <div class="loader__line-grey">
                  <div class="loader__line-white"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Carousel buttons -->
          <div class="carousel-btn">
            <a href="#" class="button left-arrow bottone" id="prevBtn" onclick="prev()">
              <i class="ri-arrow-left-s-line btn-icon-small">prev</i>
            </a>

            <a href="#" class="button right-arrow bottone" id="nextBtn" onclick="next()">
              <i class="ri-arrow-right-s-line btn-icon-small">next</i>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```